# Audio starts downloading instead of playing (Vue)

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, audio

I want to play a song after a user clicks the play button but what happens instead is that IDM (Internet Download Manager) shows a download message and stops the song and the user can't play the song anymore.

[Streaming MP3 instead of downloading it with HTML5 audio tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24221591/streaming-mp3-instead-of-downloading-it-with-html5-audio-tag)

This stackoverflow question kind of fixed it. but it introduced other issues. Good thing is that it doesn't download the song anymore but when I load it pragmatically with `audio.load()` the same thing happens and the load event doesn't work either.

Her is what I tried so far:

```html
 <audio
      @loadstart.prevent="loadStart"
      @load.prevent="onLoadedSong"
      @play.prevent
      :src="src"
      preload="none"
      aria-hidden="true"
      hidden
      id="music-track"
    ></audio>

   <button @click="play">
      Play / pause
   </button>
```

```js
export default {
  data: () => ({
    loading: false,
    musicTime: 0,
    totalTime: 100,
    audio: null,
  }),
  mounted() {
   // I had a reason to not use $ref
    this.audio = document.querySelector("audio#music-track");
  },
  methods:{
    onLoadedSong() {
      this.audio.addEventListener("timeupdate", this.updateStatus);
      this.totalTime = this.audio.duration;
      this.loading = false;
    },
    loadStart() {
      this.loading = true;
    },
    updateStatus(e) {
      this.audio = e.target;
      this.isPlaying = !this.audio.paused;
    },
    play() {
        this.audio.load();
      // Then if it's playing pause it and otherwise play it
      if (this.isPlaying) {
        this.audio.pause();
      } else {
        this.audio.play();
      }
    },
 }
}
```

So far all I know is that this happens in the load event. And it only happens in chrome and chrome based browsers (brave). I do have IDM extension installed on chrome but even after removing it it still shows the download pop-up.

Appreciate any help.