# how can i pretend to late reload when page has an audio

Tags: php, html, jquery

i have an **audio** in page and it causes page to load slower
here is my code

```
<div style="margin-left: 160px;">
    <audio controls id="audio">
      
      <source src="" type="audio/mpeg">
    
    </audio>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    
   $(document).ready(function(){
      
        $("#audio").attr('src','test3.mp3');
      
    });
    
    </script>
```

audio is almost 5min long and its size is almost 5mb. Due to this page loads very slow. Can any one have solution, thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Streaming MP3 instead of downloading it with HTML5 audio tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24221591/streaming-mp3-instead-of-downloading-it-with-html5-audio-tag)

Comment: actually i just want to minimize page load time. it take 10seconds when it has an audio and take just one second when it has no audio.. page load time increase when it has long audio

Answer (score 0):

You need to be more specific with your problem but If I understood you need:

First off all trim your audio to +-10 seconds long. It won't play for all 5 minutes anyway so there is no logic to keep that audio duration.

Then, you can include `src="test3.mp3"` directly in `audio` HTML tag. Here is the code:

```
<div style="margin-left: 160px;">
   <audio id="audio" controls src="test3.mp3" loop="loop"></audio>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
  
    $("#audio").get(0).play();
  
});

</script>
```

Comment: actually i just want to minimize page load time. it take 10seconds when it has an audio and take just one second when it has no audio.. page load time increase when it has long audio

Comment: So yeah, reducing file size by trimming audio to 5-10 seconds should definitely to make your page reload faster. A lot faster. If my original answer was helpful - please don't forget to mark that answer as "Answered". Happy to help.

Comment: yes i click on tick but i dont know how to trim audio

Comment: Use any online app like this - https://mp3cut.net/ to trim your audio file. And after that Just re-upload the file to the server or to your local environment.

Answer (score 0):

```
<audio controls id="audio">
      <source src="test3.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    </audio>
```

try this

Answer (score 0):

You could set **preload** to ***none***, then load the audio with javascript after page load. Although you will still have a time delay after the page load while the audio is streamed.

```html
<audio controls id="audio" preload="none">
  <source src="test3.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

Vanilla JS

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
  var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
  audio.play(); 
});
```

jQuery

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#audio").get(0).play();
});
```